# Phonegap 3.1 installs two shortcuts to the app, and one is broken

Tags: android, cordova

Since upgrading an existing project from phonegap 3.0 to 3.1, when I build/run it on a device, two icons of the app are created on the phone. They appear next to each other and are identical. Interestingly, only one is listed in the phone's "downloads", and uninstalling it causes both icons to disappear from the application list on the phone.

However, while tapping one of the icons runs the app as expected, tapping the other one gives an "Unfortunately, [App name] has stopped", along with throwing the following in Logcat:

```
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.fernando/com.fernando.ActivityGoogleMap}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fernando.ActivityGoogleMap
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fernando.ActivityGoogleMap
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
11-13 18:50:18.011: E/AndroidRuntime(24632):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
```

Has anyone else run into this?

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.fernando" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COMPASS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="FAlbayzin" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".ActivityGoogleMap" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Huh? I've never heard of this before. When you run the build commands, can you run them with `-d` flag and see if anything strange pops up? Maybe even have logcat running when you install the app. I've no idea why it would be installing the app twice. Does this happen if you build and install it manually with adb? `cd platforms/android/ && ant debug && adb install bin/{AppName}-debug.apk` ?

Comment: No errors are shown when running 
`$ phonegap local install -d android`
But this produces two copies of the app again.

There is a warning during ant debug:
`Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.`

But other than that, adb install of the debug apk runs smoothly, but again... two copies of the app, one of them broken.

Comment: I get that warning too when I run, but never two copies of the app. Some of the things I'm seeing about two copies talk about different the same app having different versionCode's listed in the manifest - if you try on a completely fresh device (or emulator), does it still happen?   Did you run the `phonegap platform update android` when upgrading your cordova? If you post the manifest I'll compare it with mine to see if things are wonky...sorry I'm starting to run out of ideas with this one ;)

Comment: It's weird alright. I tried it on three different devices, fresh installs, running Droid 4.1, 4.2 and 2.x. It happened on all three.

I'm adding the manifest to my post...

Comment: Hmmmm...should you have `<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter>` listed twice?  I think that will tell Android to create two default launchers, which would create two different icons on your launcher. Can you try to change one to `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` and see if it works?

Comment: I just added that line again in my manifest, (so there are two copies), and when I installed the app, it created two different icons for it.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks, that solved it! Nice catch. I'm sure I must have grabbed that from an example on google maps integration... 
Cheers!

Comment: @MBillau hey please copy out an answer so I can make it "official" -- thanks so much for the help.

Comment: will do! Glad we were able to figure that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you have this line twice:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This tells Android that you are going to have two launcher intents. This is why it creates two different icons when you install it on the device. The second launcher "class" (the GoogleMaps) (not sure of the terminology) apparently isn't set up to be an entry point into the app, which is why it fails when you tap that icon.

Change one of them to be: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>`. This will tell Android to only create one launcher icon.

This isn't an Android bug because there are some use cases where you'd want to have two different entry points into the app.... for example maybe a "light" and "dark" theme or something.